# NHibernate MappingException, No persister for: NHiberDeneme.Sinifi

Tags: nhibernate

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=hiberdb;Integrated Security=True;</property>
      <property name="default_schema">hiberdb.dbo</property>
      <mapping assembly="NHiberDeneme"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate;

namespace NHiberDeneme
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.AddAssembly("NHibernate"); // projenin assembly Adi
            ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
            ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
            Sinifi sinif = new Sinifi();
            sinif.Id = 1;
            sinif.SinifAdi = "sinif adi";
            session.Save(sinif);
            session.Flush();
            session.Clear();
            transaction.Commit();
            session.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Sinifi.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate.Mapping;

namespace NHiberDeneme  
{
    class Sinifi 
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _sinifadi;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public string SinifAdi
        {
            get { return _sinifadi; }
            set { _sinifadi = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Sinifi.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.0">
  <class name="NHiberDeneme.Sinifi, NHiberDeneme.Program, NHiberDeneme" table="Sinifi" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="SinifAdi" column="SinifAdi" type="String" length="10"/>


    <bag name="SinifiId" table="SinifiId" inverse="true">
      <key column="Id" />
      <one-to-one class="NHiberDeneme.Sinifi, NHiberDeneme.Program, NHiberDeneme" />
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my sql relation here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOT5M.jpg

*Gives me "MappingException, No persister for: NHiberDeneme.Sinifi" error. I tried many ways, I did embeded resource too.*

Answer (score 0):

With this error NHibernate tells you that there's something wrong with your class mapping. NHibernate either couldn't find the class mapping, or couldn't parse it correctly.

By looking at it, your class name in mapping file seems to be wrong.

From NHibernate's documentation on [`class mapping`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class):

> **name**: The fully qualified .NET class name of the persistent class (or
>   interface), including its assembly name.

In your code, you have this for class name: `NHiberDeneme.Sinifi, NHiberDeneme.Program, NHiberDeneme`. This is not a valid [.NET assembly qualified class name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). If your assembly name is `NHiberDeneme`, you should have this:

```
<class name="NHiberDeneme.Sinifi, NHiberDeneme" ... />
```

...and if assembly name is `NHiberDeneme.Program` mapping should look like this:

```
<class name="NHiberDeneme.Sinifi, NHiberDeneme.Program" ... />
```